# Dynamic connector configurations with Mule, specifically MySQL database name?

Tags: mysql, database, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have been trying to connect to with MySQL but passing in dynamic connection parameters, such as Database name and Server location as the setup I am working with has many databases to connect with. I have tried using MEL but it always outputs with single quotes and MySQL doesnt like this. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Ash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this same problem (the only difference is connect with MS SQL Server). Looking at the snippet below.

```
<jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="sqlDataSource" user="root" password="root" url="jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver;databaseName=test1" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source">
</jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source>
```

Seeing the above code, it could be test1, test2, abc or whatever according to what I'm passing in. E.g. I pass in localhost:8080/test2 then it would be

```
url="jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver;databaseName=test2"
```

**Question:** How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you got the answer to this problem ?